UML/OCL implementation of Namespace::getNamesOfMember()
This is defined on page 93 of the UML 2.5.1 specification under section 7.8.10.6 "Operations" for Namespace. I have reformatted the body with my own indentation and line numbering of the body text for easier understanding (I hope!):
getNamesOfMember(element : NamedElement) : String [0..*]

The query getNamesOfMember() gives a set of all of the names that a member would have in a Namespace,
taking importing into account. In general a member can have multiple names in a Namespace if it is imported
more than once with different aliases.

body:
 1 | if self.ownedMember ->includes(element)
 2 | then Set{element.name}
 3 | else
 4 |   let elementImports : Set(ElementImport)
 5 |      = self.elementImport->select(ei | ei.importedElement = element)
 6 |        in
 7 |        if elementImports->notEmpty() -- <== ???
 8 |        then
 9 |          elementImports->collect(el | el.getName())
10 |          ->asSet()
11 |        else
12 |          self.packageImport->select(
13 |             pi | pi.importedPackage.visibleMembers().oclAsType(NamedElement)
14 |              ->includes(element))
15 |                -> collect(pi | pi.importedPackage.getNamesOfMember(element))
16 |                   ->asSet()
17 |        endif
18 | endif

It seems to me that if the Namespace has any ElementImports, none of the elements originating from any PackageImports would be included in the output due to the innermost if..then..else section starting at line 7?
As far as I understand, a Namespace can have PackageImports and also ElementImports from a different Package, possibly having name conflicts.
Perhaps there is an extra (or missing) parenthesis somewhere?

Aha ... elementImports, although having a plural form as its name, is the temporary set constructed from a single ElementImport which has the input element as its importedElement (or an empty Set if it isn't found) ... and elementImport, although the name suggests it is a single ElementImport, is in fact a set of (possibly) multiple ElementImports. Looks like the function looks in the member elementImport(s) first for a match to element, and if none is found, searches the packageImport(s). I was confused by the typical UML naming scheme.

There is certainly ample scope for confusion. Be aware that much of the OCL in the UML specification was written by comparative OCL novices without the aid of strong OCL tooling. It was not until I ran the UML 2.5 draft through Eclipse OCL that the hundred of syntax/semantic errors were resolved; 4 late discoveries got through.

AFAIAA the OCL has never been executed in earnest, rather tool vendors have transliterated, typically to Java. The vendors failed to report any syntax/semantic/functional errors. Once I had semantically sound OCL text, I did try executing it. It was incredibly slow (tens of minutes for UML self-validation) due to many high order collection operations which scream out for an optimizer. Vendors had obviously hand optimized and applied common sense.
